# How to edit and save a .bst file?

Tags: bibtex, miktex

I want to edit a `apalike.bst` to suit my bibliography style requirements.

The path of this file on my Windows OS is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.7\bibtex\bst\apalike.bst
```

I made a copy of it, named `myapalike.bst`. I used notepad to open it and made the required changes. Then, while saving it, it showed a warning "Access is denied". And the changes were not saved.

Comment: Real quick: Are you really still working with version 2.7 of MiKTeX? Version 2.9 has been the standard for quite a few years by now. Separately, into which directory are you trying to save `myapalike.bst`? Are you maybe trying to save it to a directory for which you have no write access?

Comment: I am trying to save it in  C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.7\bibtex\bst

Comment: It's a bad idea to try to save a personal file in a directory located in the MiKTeX *system* directory tree. Try to save the bst file either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a "local" root directory -- assuming, of course, that you've set up such a root directory.

Comment: @Mico: @Qwerty should check his search pathes, to find out, where the personal LaTeX-directories are.    In TeXLive this would be `tlmgr conf`.  Have a look for the variable `TEXMFLOCAL` and store your newly created file in there.  Second: if you have write permissions to C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.7\bibtex\bst and store your file there, it might not be found by LaTeX/BibTeX, as long as you don't update the TeX-systems database.

Comment: The following question might be of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483/93559

Comment: Save the file in a folder `C:\mylocaltexmf\bibtex\bst\myapalike`. Instead of `C:\mylocaltexmf` you can use whatever location you want. It only should be outside of the miktex trees, and be writable by you. Then add `C:\mylocaltexmf` as a new root with miktex-settings.